# Everything is fine on wp preview until i upload it to my website, why?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.text-block {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -27px;
  left: 38%;
  right: 38%;
  background-color: #ff6900;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/315755/pexels-photo-315755.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" alt="Pizza" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="text-block">
    <center><h4>Pizza</h4></center>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to add this to my wordpress website and it is perfectly fine on preview as you can see in here
[image: Goal]

But it just becomes like that when i publish it. What causes that and how can i fix it? [image: Problem]

Comment: Have you inspected the element in the dev console to see whether any classes or existing theme styles are overriding anything?

Comment: I changed the whole css and it's working know. ``` .container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.text-block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 99.5%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #ff6900;
  padding: 10px;
} ```